# Take the Input from the user using get and set method in c++?

Tags: c++, string, get, set

I m using get and set method and in c++.
I want to take the input from user and print that string uppercase

for ex:

When User
Enter the Name:**alex**
then
o/p is **ALEX**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

class abc
{
    private: 
    string name_;

     //take the input from the user
     //cout << "Enter the Name: ";
     //cin >> name_;

    public: 

      string getname()
      {
        return name_;
      }

      string setname(string name)
      {
          name_=name;
      }
};

int main()
{
  abc a;
  string name_=a.getname();
  cout << name_;

  _name(toupper(name_));

  return 0;
}
```

I Know the one function is isupper() and I refer this link:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/

I m trying to get the Input from the user and print that string in upper case but give an error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:44:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘toupper(std::string&)’
   _name(toupper(name_));
                      ^
```

what I m trying to do:
https://onlinegdb.com/SyZnXIkUI

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Can you explain in more detail? If the commented out code is not relevant please delete it

Comment: The whole point of using a get and set method to provide access to a field is because you don't want to expose your field directly. Your string name_ needs to be private.

Comment: @Eric thanks I change my code can u help more when user enter ```rahul then O/p is RAHUL```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper Converts the given **character** to uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that toupper() is not taking std::string, it just takes a single char. So to convert a whole string to uppercase you whould need to do something like this:

```
std::string text;

std::cin >> text;

for(auto &c : text)
{
    c = toupper(c);
}
```

Comment: your program is static I want to take the Input from the user can u help more still I m trying to solve the problem

Comment: @Rahul I edited my answer. I assumed you know how cin works because it already was in your question (commented out)